# I am using a html template for a new website. It is using SASS styles but I would like to only use CSS. How can I get rid of the SASS stylesheets

Tags: html, css, sass, stylesheet

When I inspect in Chrome it will give me a location of the SASS styles but the file location does not exist in my website folder.

Image of what Chrome inspector displays

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking the browser is using the CSS but with source maps. What's inconvenient about this setup for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look in the `<head>` of the file for a link to the scss file. There's likely to be a `<style>` element there that imports the scss stylesheet. If it's not in the `<head>` it might be somewhere else in the document, I'd check the end next. You can remove the link to the scss file and replace it with a link to your own css file.

Answer (score 1):

SASS is a powerful extension of CSS , there are plenty of SASS to CSS converters are available online, like 
[sassmeister](http://www.sassmeister.com)

You can convert the sass to css, and add it with your Html file.

If you're are comfortable with SASS you can use gulp like compilers.